# How to use variables of one php file in to an other

Tags: php

How to use variables of one php file in to an other??

I am trying to increment count variable of database if one  button is pressed and decrement when another button pressed in php.

Need answer very urgently.
Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very urgently? than very urgently use `$_SESSION`

Store the value in a session like this

```
$_SESSION['whatever'] = $value_holder;
```

> Note: Don't forget to use `session_start()` at the very top of your
>   website, also you need to use conditions to increment decrement value
>   of that session